# Bcrypt for password hashing because it is slow?

Tags: security, hash

I read today on [not-implemented.com](http://www.not-implemented.com/comparing-hash-algorithms-md5-sha1-sha2/) :

> Sha-256 should be chosen in most cases where a high speed hash function is desired. It is considered secure with no known theoretical vulnerabilities and it has a reasonable digest size of 32 bytes. For things like hashing user password, though, a function designed to be slow is preferred: a great one is bcrypt.

Can somebody explain the last sentence :

> For things like hashing user password, though, a function designed to be slow is preferred: a great one is bcrypt.

I don't say it's not correct, my question is simply:

Why it is preferred for hashing user password to use a slow function ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because if it takes more time to hash the value, it also takes a much longer time to [brute-force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) the password.

Keep in mind that slow means that it requires more computing power. The same goes for when a potential hacker tries to brute-force a password.

Answer (score 19):

On your side, the password hash needs to be computed rather rarely. But an attacker who tries to brute force a password from a stolen hash, relies on computing as many hashes as possible.

So, if your login now takes 100 ms instead of 0.1 (probably less) that's not really a problem for you. But it makes a huge difference for an attacker if he needs 2000 days to break a password instead of 2 days.

bcrypt is designed to be slow and not to allow any shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

It takes more effort to brute force attack the password. The slower the algorithm, the less guesses can be made per second. The extra time won't be noticed by a user of the system, but will make it harder to crack the password.

Answer (score -3):

Brute force a hash password?. It's easy to say than done.

If the passwords are not using a SALT then it is possible to break it, no matter the kind of encryption (because we could use a dictionary / pre-calculated hash attack).

**The speed of the algorithm means nothing**, it's just a myth that some people are spreading for the wrong reasons.

For example the next example:

Our hash is generated with the next formula:

```
 MD5(SALT+MD5(SALT+VALUE))
```

Even if we could generate every possible combination of md5 in a split of a second, **how we know if we found the right value?**.  And the answer is no, it's not possible. MD5 (or sha) doesn't check if the value is right or not, it simply generates a sequence of values and nothing more.

**We could try a force brute attack if and only if we have a way to determine if our hash generated match some criteria**. These criteria could be a dictionary and it means a slow process too and only if we could find some criteria.